# Big-O notation of an algorithm that runs max(n,0) times?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, complexity-theory

I have the following algorithm:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if(j % i == 0) System.out.println(i + " " + j);
```

This will run `max(n,0)` times.

Would the Big-O notation be `O(n)`? If not, what is it and why?

Thank you.

Comment: The inner loop runs `i` times, for `i` from `1` to `n-1`, so see what `1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)` adds up to. But if you want to count the `println` lines, only, then that only gets executed when `j = 0`.

Comment: So, the performance is it is `O(n)`, right?

Comment: Could be `O(n)`, or it could be `O(n^2)`. Time complexity is defined in terms of what you (choose to) consider elementary operations.

Comment: Thank you. What are my choices?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated what you are trying to measure with the Big-O notation. Let's assume it's *time complexity*. Next we have to define what the dependent variable is against which you want to measure the complexity. A reasonable choice here is the *absolute value* of `n` (as opposed to the bit-length), since you are dealing with fixed-length `int`s and not arbitrary-length integers.

You are right that the `println` is executed O(n) times, but that's counting how often a certain line is hit, it's not measuring *time complexity*.

It's easy to see that the `if` statement is hit `O(n^2)` times, so we have already established that the time complexity is bounded from below by `Omega(n^2)`. As a commenter has already noted, the if-condition is only true for `j=0`, so I suspect that you actually meant to write `i % j` instead of `j % i`? This matters because the time complexity of the `println(i + " " + j)`-statement is certainly not `O(1)`, but `O(log n)` (you can't possibly print `x` characters in less than `x` steps), so at first sight there is a possibility that the overall complexity is strictly worse than `O(n^2)`.

Assuming that you meant to write `i % j` we could make the simplifying assumption that the condition is always true, in which case we would obtain the upper bound `O(n^2 log n)`, which is strictly worse than `O(n^2)`!

However, noting that the number of divisors of `n` is bounded by `O(Sqrt(n))`, we actually have `O(n^2 + n*Sqrt(n)*log(n))`. But since `O(Sqrt(n) * log(n)) < O(n)`, this amounts to `O(n^2)`.

You can dig deeper into number theory to find [tighter bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133306/best-upper-bound-on-the-number-of-divisors-of-n-that-are-larger-than-n) on the number of divisors, but that doesn't make a difference since the `n^2` stays the dominating factor.

So the tightest upper bound is indeed `O(n^2)`, but it's not as obvious as it seems at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

`max(n,0)` would indeed be `O(n)`. However, your algorithm is in `O(n**2)`. Your first loop goes `n` times, and the second loop goes `i` times which is on average `n/2`. That makes `O(n**2 / 2) = O(n**2)`. However, unlike the runtime of the algorithm, the amount of times `println` is reached is in `O(n)`, as this happens exactly `n` times.

So, the answer depends on what exactly you want to measure.